# Python3.11 Asyncio: Is it possible to create two concurrent TaskGroups? If so, is it possible to also "restart" a TaskGroup after it is cancelled?

Tags: asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-3.11

I have an Asyncio program that I want to have some loop functions be "safe" from cancellation and others to be cancelled if an exception is raised (i.e. Tasks 0-2 need to be "safe" and Tasks 3-5 need to be cancellable.
I read about how `TaskGroup`s in Python 3.11 can allow for the latter of these two points.

So I tried this while `shield`ing the "safe" loops (using a simple decorator) to make sure they weren't cancelled:

```py
_task_list: List[asyncio.Task] = []

# handle exceptions
try:
    async with self.task_group_safe as tg:
        for task in [
            self.task0(),
            self.task1(),
            self.task2(),
            self.task3(),
            self.task4(),
            self.task5(),
        ]:
            t = tg.create_task(task)
            _task_list.append(t)

except* AbortException as err:
    print(f"{err=}")
await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

NOTE: `task5` is just a `while` loop to check if a flag has been set, and if so an exception is raised.

However, when I raise the exception, the `TaskGroup` outputs that all tasks have been cancelled, even though the first 3 are `shield`ed and still appear to be running:

```py
for i, task in enumerate(_task_list):
    print(f"Task{i}: done={task.done()}, cancelled={task.cancelled()}")
```

```
Task0: done=True, cancelled=True
Task1: done=True, cancelled=True
Task2: done=True, cancelled=True
Task3: done=True, cancelled=True
Task4: done=True, cancelled=True
Task5: done=True, cancelled=False
```

So I had the idea to see if I could separate out the tasks into two `TaskGroup`s and remove the need for `shield`ing the first 3 tasks, such as:

```py
_task_list: List[asyncio.Task] = []

tg1: List[Coroutine[Any, Any, Any]] = [
    self.task1(),
    self.task2(),
    self.task3(),
]
tg2: List[Coroutine[Any, Any, Any]] = [
    self.task4(),
    self.task5(),
    self.task6(),
]

async def create_task_group(
    task_group: asyncio.TaskGroup, tasks: List[Coroutine[Any, Any, Any]]
) -> None:
    # handle exceptions
    try:
        async with task_group as tg:
            for task in tasks:
                t = tg.create_task(task)
                _task_list.append(t)
    except* AbortException as err:
        print(f"{err=}")
    await asyncio.sleep(0)

await create_task_group(self.task_group_1, tg1)
await create_task_group(self.task_group_2, tg2)

for i, task in enumerate(_task_list):
    print(f"Task{i}: done={task.done()}, cancelled={task.cancelled()}")
```

Obviously, in this case the second `TaskGroup` never gets created. As the program gets stuck on the `await create_task_group(self.task_group_1, tg1)`.

I also tried:

```py
async def create_task_groups(
    task_group: asyncio.TaskGroup,
    tasks: List[Coroutine[Any, Any, Any]],
    task_group2: asyncio.TaskGroup,
    tasks2: List[Coroutine[Any, Any, Any]],
) -> None:
    # handle exceptions
    try:
        async with task_group as tg, task_group2 as tg2:
            for task in tasks:
                t = tg.create_task(task)
                _task_list.append(t)
            for task in tasks2:
                t2 = tg2.create_task(task)
                _task_list.append(t2)
    except* AbortException as err:
        print(f"{err=}")
    await asyncio.sleep(0)

await create_task_groups(self.task_group_1, tg1, self.task_group_2, tg2)
```

But this just had the same outcome as the first example I gave.

So...

***Question 1:***
Is it even possible to have two `TaskGroup`s running concurrently?

And

***Question 2:***
If it is possible to have two `TaskGroup`s running concurrently, is it possible to restart the second one after it has been cancelled?

Any help, or even other ways to write this code, would be greatly appreciated. :)

_

EDIT:
This is the decorator I use to shield the task functions:

```py
def _shielded(func: _AsyncFuncType) -> _AsyncFuncType:
    """
    Makes so an awaitable method is always shielded from cancellation
    """

    async def _shield(*args, **kwargs):
        return await asyncio.shield(func(*args, **kwargs))

    return _shield
```

`_AsyncFuncType` is just an alias for `Callable[..., Coroutine[Any, Any, Any]]`

Comment: Can you also share your decorator code for shielding the task from cancellation?

Comment: @SuibianP I have updated the post with the decorator code :)